# Pandas MultiIndex, selecting values by 1. and 2. level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I´ve some problems by selecting values within 1. and 2. level.

> I´ve got an MultiIndex by setting the `header = [0,1]`

```
In[1]:  df = pd.read_csv('Data.txt', sep='\t', header=[0,1], skipinitialspace=True)

In[2]:  print(df.columns)

Out[2]: MultiIndex(
        levels=[['20052065', '20052066', '20052082', '20052087', '20052089'], 
                ['CTF1', 'CTF2', 'CTF3', 'CTF_M', 'CTM1', 'CTM2', 'CTM3', 'CTM_M']],
        labels=[[...]],
        names=[...])
```

> If it try to get the data of the 2. level value and selected element
>   from 1. level i get the following output:

```
In[3]:  print(df['20052065'][['CTF1','CTF_M']])

Out[3]: TIME[s]     CTF1    CTF_M
        0.000    -14.386   14.963
        60.000   -26.937   34.729
        120.000  -29.986   58.265
            ...      ...      ...
```

> Now i tried to generate the output for 2 Elements and did something like this:

```
In[4]:  print(df[['20052065','20052066']][['CTF1','CTF_M']])

Out[4]: KeyError: "['CTF1' 'CTF_M'] not in index"
```

Somehow this doesn´t work. Maybe you know what terrible went wrong?

Thanks for help.

**Edit:** `In[1]: print(df)` looks like:

```
Out[1]:          ELEMENT 20052065 20052066 20052082 20052087 20052089 20052090  \
       TIME[s]   TEMP[C]     CTF1     CTF1     CTF1     CTF1     CTF1     CTF1   
       0.000      24.000   -4.234   -6.728  -14.386   -4.356   -6.926  -10.205   
       60.000     36.137  -29.308  -24.795  -26.937  -30.134  -24.735  -23.474 
          ...        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
```

**The *.txt file looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `df.loc`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B','C'],['X','Y','Z']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,len(columns))), columns=columns)
#    A        B        C      
#    X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
# 0  2  7  5  1  6  0  5  0  0
# 1  8  4  7  2  0  8  7  3  9
# 2  0  6  8  8  1  1  8  0  2

# In some cases `sort_index` may be needed to avoid UnsortedIndexError
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print(df.loc[:, (['A','B'],['X','Y'])])
```

yields (something like):

```
   A     B   
   X  Y  X  Y
0  2  7  1  6
1  8  4  2  0
2  0  6  8  1
```

---

If you only want to select, say, the `('A','Y')` and `('B','X')` columns, then note that you can specify MultiIndexed columns as tuples:

```
In [37]: df.loc[:, [('A','Y'),('B','X')]]
Out[37]: 
   A  B
   Y  X
0  7  1
1  4  2
2  6  8
```

or even just `df[[('A','Y'),('B','X')]]` (which yields the same result).

And in general it is better to use a single indexer such as `df.loc[...]` instead of double indexing (e.g. `df[...][...]`). It can be quicker (because it makes fewer calls to `__getitem__`, and generates fewer temporary sub-DataFrames) and `df.loc[...] = value` it is [the correct way](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) to make assignments to sub-slices of a DataFrame which modify `df` itself.

---

The reason why `df[['A','B']][['X','Y']]` would not work is because
`df[['A','B']]` returns a DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

```
In [36]: df[['A','B']]
Out[36]: 
   A        B      
   X  Y  Z  X  Y  Z
0  2  7  5  1  6  0
1  8  4  7  2  0  8
2  0  6  8  8  1  1
```

So indexing this DataFrame with `['X','Y']` fails because there are no top-level column labels named `'X'` or `'Y'`.

---

Sometimes, depending on how the DataFrame was constructed (or due to operations performed on the DataFrame) the MultiIndex needs to be lexsorted before it can be sliced. There is a [boxed warning in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers) mentioning this issue. To lexsort the column index use

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Again i got the following output: `UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'` :-/

Comment: In that case, use `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` to sort the column index.

Comment: thanks for help! this works! :) thank you very much. :)

Comment: unutbu, another question: i would like to get a list from the 1. level attributes like: `elements = df.iloc[0,1:-1].index.levels[0][0:-2]` and place them like: `print(df.loc[:, ([elements],['CTF1','CTF_M'])])` but with an "object" it results in a TypeError. Just work´s if i do it like: ``elements = df.iloc[0,1:-1].index.levels[0][0]`` for 1 Element. Is there a way to get all of the values in a List?

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, you could use `df.loc[:, (elements,['CTF1','CTF_M'])]` -- that is, simply remove the brackets surrounding `elements`. You could get all the values in a list by using `list(elements)` too. Finally, I think you could use `elements = df.columns.levels[0][0:-2]` instead of `df.iloc[0,1:-1].index.levels[0][0:-2]` because slicing `df` does not alter the index levels, only the labels. (To see what I mean, compare `df.iloc[0, 1:-1].index` with `df.columns`.)

Comment: ok, thanks for help. i did it this way: `elements = df.columns.get_level_values(0)[0:8].tolist()` works well. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think need [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
print (df)
  20052065 20052066 20052065 20052066 20052065 20052066
      CTF1    CTF_M   CTF_M1   CTF_Mr        V        A
0        1        2        4        5        6        7

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[:, idx[['20052065','20052066'], ['CTF1','CTF_M']]])
  20052065 20052066
      CTF1    CTF_M
0        1        2
```

Comment: I´ve tried it and got the following output: `UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'`

Comment: Check modified solution - need `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`